# Unused type parameter in swift

Tags: swift

Is there a keyword to place-hold unused type parameters?

In this example, `receiver` does not use `T` of `MyGen`.
In Java language, it can be written `MyGen<?> v`.
I could not find a counterpart in swift language documents.

```
import Foundation
class MyGen<T: Printable> {
    var value: T
    init(v: T) {
        value = v
    }
}

func receiver(v: MyGen<WHAT_COMES_HERE>) {
    println(v);
}

let s = MyGen<NSString>(v: "hello")
receiver(s)
```

I know that giving `receiver` a type parameter solves the problem, but it is not welcome because upper bound `Printable` is repeated as many as functions and the code has redundant information.

```
// This works, but not welcome
func receiver<T: Printable>(v: MyGen<T>) {
    println(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, despite it not being used, you have to declare a type parameters. But, you don't need `:Printable` in here, You can use just `T` or whatever as you like.

```
func receiver<A>(v: MyGen<A>) {
    println(v)
}
```

Use `:` for the type parameter, only if `receiver` requires more specialized `MyGet.T`. For example:

```
class MyGen<T: Printable> {
    var value: T
    init(v: T) {
        value = v
    }
}

// `receiver` accepts `MyGen` only if its `T` is a sequence of `Int` 
func receiver<A: SequenceType where A.Generator.Element == Int>(v: MyGen<A>) {
    println(reduce(v.value, 0, +))
}

let s = MyGen<[Int]>(v: [1,2,3])
receiver(s) // ->  6
```